# How to set mpdf library in codeigniter support with all unicode?

Tags: codeigniter, mpdf

currently i have converted html to pdf using mpdf library, but it doesn't support with my language(Khmer) i try to use utf-8 but it not work anyone has idea please kindly tell me it agent cause :)

Comment: See this: http://www.mpdfonline.com/repos/mpdfmanual.pdf page no:18 end of page.. they have mentioned that **Khmer** language is not supported

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the mode on object creation

```
$mpdf = new Mpdf(['mode' => 'UTF-8']);
```

if you are sure that your html is utf-8